# Are Singletons good to manage Locales/Localization/Internationalization?

Tags: java, localization, internationalization, singleton, locale

I'm working on an application which has multiple strings and I want to implement at least my native language and english, to use locales I need a ResourceBundle and since I have **many** classes I thought it would be great to have only one instance of the ResourceBundle inside the Singleton.

Is this a common practice? Good, bad, or there is a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of maintainability I would not advice to do the logic on the code and if that was the hypothesis I would probably use static strings.

The best and more common solution IMHO, is using a **database to map the translations** having the key and locale as UNIQUE KEY `key - value - locale` for example ${username} would have two entrances with different locales.

- ${username} - The name of the user - en-US
- ${username} - O nome do utilizador - pt-PT

This would avoid having to make new code and a new commit every-time you want to change the translations. A new commit is more errors that could enter in your code.

Comment: I do not understand what do you mean with "logic on the code"

Comment: If you have all the translations on the codebase you have to make a commit + deploy if you want to change the translations. On the database that is not true. You do the code once and if it's generic enough you can only do minor alterations on the database. If you want to introduce other language it's only a db script.

Answer (score 0):

Singletons are good yes. Think you don't need to hold different state into  instances, so getting the same instance is worthy.